# Index single Xml-file with Lucene

Tags: java, xml, indexing, solr, lucene

I'm writing a Java application and want to index an Xml-file with Lucene so I can search for a drug that has a given target. The file size is 400MB and it is filled with over 8000 drug-entries.

```xml
<drug type="biotech" created="2005-06-13" updated="2015-11-27">
    <drugbank-id primary="true">DB00001</drugbank-id>
    <drugbank-id>BIOD00024</drugbank-id>
    <drugbank-id>BTD00024</drugbank-id>
    <name>Lepirudin</name>
    ....
    <targets>
        <target position="1">
            <id>BE0000767</id>
            <name>Epidermal growth factor receptor</name>
            ....
        </target>
        ....
    </targets>
</drug>
<drug>
....
</drug>
```

How can I index this file so one drug-entry is one Document?
If someone has some useful links/resources or tips on how to index this Xml please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible strategy is usually to [just use SolrJ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ) through a small java application that reads the file and transforms it to a suitable format for indexing in Solr. That way you can easily preprocess certain fields before they're received by Solr.

Another option is to [use XSL to transform the XML file into something that Solr understands](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltUpdateRequestHandler). This can be used either server-side (as with XSLTUpdateRequestHandler linked) or client-side (transform an XML document into an update request and submit it to the standard request handler).

Comment: Hi again and thanks for the reply, should I use embeddedSolrServer for this? I want to index the xml files when my app/plugin starts and querried multiple times when the plugin is used and then re-index the files on the next startup. Do I need to preprocess and index each drug-field programmatically  or can I use the schema.xml? Any good tutorials on making and using schema.xml?